# groupby in pandas with custom function over a subset of rows in each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a pandas DataFrame of the following format:

**Input**:

```
                                     X    [OTHER_COLUMNS]
version     branch                      
v0          overall  2475.0         -1         .
v1          overall  2475.0         -1         .
            A        1712.5          1         .
            B         257.5          2         .
            C         392.5          2
            D         112.5          3
v2          overall  2475.0         -1
            A        2341.5          1
            B          95.0          2
            C          38.5          2
v3          overall  2475.0         -1
            A        2000.0          1
            B         475.0          2
v4          overall  2475.0         -1
            A        2341.5          1
            B         133.5          1
```

where `(version, branch)` is a MultiIndex.

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**:

I want to `groupby` `version` and set the values in the column `X` with `branch` `overall` to the sum of the values in the column `X` for the remaining branches (having the same `version`), weighted by the values in the column `N`. For groups (i.e. `version`s) which have only one branch (named `overall`), I want `X` to be set to `1`.

**EXAMPLE**:

For `version` `v2`, the value in the cell with column `X` and `branch` `overall` should be

`(2341.5 * 1 + 95.0 * 2 + 38.5 * 2) / 2475.0 = 1.05393939394`,

and in pseudo-code:

`(A_N  * A_X +  B_N  * B_X) / overall_N`.

Note: For a given `version`, the value in column `N` and `branch` `overall` will always be equal to the sum of the values in column `N` for the other `branch`'es.

**IDEA AND QUESTION**:

I think I have to do the following:

`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'overall'], 'X'] = df.groupby('version').apply(...)`

where `df` is the DataFrame and where `...` is to be replaced by a custom function.

I am looking for help in constructing such a function.

**Expected output**:

```
                          N          X
version     branch                      
v0          overall  2475.0          1         
v1          overall  2475.0          1.35353535354
            A        1712.5          1
            B         257.5          2
            C         392.5          2
            D         112.5          3
v2          overall  2475.0          1.05393939394
            A        2341.5          1
            B          95.0          2
            C          38.5          2
v3          overall  2475.0          1.19191919192
            A        2000.0          1
            B         475.0          2
v4          overall  2475.0          1
            A        2341.5          1
            B         133.5          1
```

**Explaination of expected output**:

```
(1712.5 * 1 + 257.5 * 2 + 392.5 * 2 + 112.5 * 3) / 2475.0 = 1.35353535354

(2341.5 * 1 + 95.0 * 2 + 38.5 * 2) / 2475.0 = 1.05393939394

(2000.0 * 1 + 475.0 * 2) / 2475.0 = 1.19191919192

(2341.5 * 1 + 133.5 * 1) / 2475.0 = 1
```

**CODE TO CREATE DATAFRAME**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.array(
        [
            [2475.0, 2475.0, 1712.5, 257.5, 392.5, 112.5, 2475.0, 2341.5, 95.0, 38.5, 2475.0, 2000.0, 475.0, 2475.0, 2341.5, 133.5],
            [-1, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, -1, 1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 2, -1, 1, 1]
        ]
    ).T,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        tuples=[
            ('v0', 'overall'),
            ('v1', 'overall'),
            ('v1', 'A'),
            ('v1', 'B'),
            ('v1', 'C'),
            ('v1', 'D'),
            ('v2', 'overall'),
            ('v2', 'A'),
            ('v2', 'B'),
            ('v2', 'C'),
            ('v3', 'overall'),
            ('v3', 'A'),
            ('v3', 'B'),
            ('v4', 'overall'),
            ('v4', 'A'),
            ('v4', 'B'),
        ],
        names=['version', 'branch'],
    ),
    columns=['N', 'X'],
)
```

---

```
print (df)
                      N    X
version branch              
v0      overall  2475.0 -1.0
v1      overall  2475.0 -1.0
        A        1712.5  1.0
        B         257.5  2.0
        C         392.5  2.0
        D         112.5  3.0
v2      overall  2475.0 -1.0
        A        2341.5  1.0
        B          95.0  2.0
        C          38.5  2.0
v3      overall  2475.0 -1.0
        A        2000.0  1.0
        B         475.0  2.0
v4      overall  2475.0 -1.0
        A        2341.5  1.0
        B         133.5  1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#select overalls only
overall = df['N'].xs('overall', level=1)
#select all rows without overalls
df1 = df.drop('overall', level=1)

#multiple and aggregate sum, divide overalls   
s = df1['N'].mul(df1['X']).groupby(level=0).sum().div(overall)

#create MultiIndex and assign back
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'overall'], 'X'] = pd.concat({'overall':s}).swaplevel(0,1)
```

---

```
print (df)
                      N         X
version branch                   
v1      overall  2475.0  1.353535
        A        1712.5  1.000000
        B         257.5  2.000000
        C         392.5  2.000000
        D         112.5  3.000000
v2      overall  2475.0  1.053939
        A        2341.5  1.000000
        B          95.0  2.000000
        C          38.5  2.000000
v3      overall  2475.0  1.191919
        A        2000.0  1.000000
        B         475.0  2.000000
v4      overall  2475.0  1.000000
        A        2341.5  1.000000
        B         133.5  1.000000
```

Comment: When I run it, the result is completly different than the expected results. Basically, the column 'X' is now all zeros and ones, besides one entry which is 0.691919.

Comment: @Filip - input data are different like mentioned in part `Input`, changed in question.

Comment: @Filip - btw, very nice a and good created question, super!!!